# How long does it take for me to get food at the buffet line if there are "cheaters"?

Tags: physics, mathematical-modeling

This is a real life problem. On my way home from work I have to clear a traffic jam at the 605-405 on-ramp in California. At this junction there are 4 lanes, the two on the left merge onto 405, the two on the right go straight and exit into the city. Cheaters like to use the right 2 lanes (which are not congested) to get to the front of the line and then merge in. At peak hours, it can be backed up for 3/4 of a mile.

The issue is: the more people cheat, the longer it takes for honest people in the back to clear the jam. But as they spend more time in the back, even more cheaters get to cheat on them. So there is compounding.

I would like to find the formula for how long it takes to get to the front of the line `f(h,d,x)` where:

- *h* is the throughput at the front of the line (cars/minute)
- *d* is my distance from the front of the line (cars)
- *x* is rate of cheaters (cars/minute)

Technically the cheaters often start merging in around 1/8 mile from the front of the line.  But for simplicity let's assume they always merge in at the very front. And yes, this injustice bothers me to no end.

**ANALOGY**

*How long does it take for me to get my food at the buffet line if there are cheaters?*

Assuming cheaters always jump in at the front of the line, I'd like to find the formula for how long it takes for me to get food `f(h,d,x)` where:

- *h* is the throughput at the front of the line (persons per minute)
- *d* is my distance from the front of the line (persons)
- *x* is the rate of cheaters (persons per minute)

Comment: what is the percentage of people that are cheaters ?

Comment: well, I'd say 1%, but it doesn't seem to be relevant.  Btw, here's the pin: https://goo.gl/maps/xiSPXv12c642.  At peak, _h_ is around 60 cars per minute, _c_ is around 15 cars per minute.

Comment: math is exacting. also why else would cheater cars per minute matter.

Comment: I think you get the idea, please feel free to model it anyway you like, don't have to use my variables.

Comment: there's a  lot more complexity to it than you think though. it's not just he rate of cheater cars it's the rate of the ones behind you that matters. etc.

Comment: Yes I'm making the simplifying assumption that the rate is constant, and that all cheaters merge in at the very front

Comment: What does "how long does it take to clear the traffic jam?" mean? Surely what you really care about is your overall journey time. Cheating at bottlenecks is likely to be completely irrelevant to that. Have you calibrated your journey times against Google Maps predictions?

Comment: Google Maps predictions are good, but it always direct me through this route, there is no faster route. But consider a buffet line at your favorite buffet restaurant. If this problem occurs, how would you feel about that.

Comment: $\frac{d}{h-c}$?

Comment: I changed variable c to x. I believe your formula doesn't account for the compounding issue. We may want to restate this question using the example of a buffet line at a buffet restaurant. It may be easier to think about.

Comment: Google Maps is giving you the journey time for you **and** the cheaters. The cheaters gain a few seconds at a point where the traffic is going really slowly, but that's a trivial advantage.

Comment: Good point about Google Maps, but once we have a formula, and we plug in some real numbers, we'll see that cheating can save you up to a few minutes, even 5 minutes, as I can testify in my own experience.

Comment: Here’s a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :) Very inspired question, by the way!

Comment: Thanks for the MathJax link. By the way I believe the answer to this involves an integral.

Comment: @HaiPhan you know you can edit and add this to the question with enough reputation right ?

Comment: @DanielSchepler you had the right answer actually

Comment: I am voting to close this, because your edit that adds the analogy leads to a gross over-simplification of the original question. The parameters $h$, $d$ and $x$ that you identify won't be enough for the original question - queuing at a a buffet line is significantly simpler than queuing on a 4-lane highway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model, the cheaters are stealing processing time.  The $h$ persons per minute is shared between the cheaters and the noncheaters.  As we are given that $x$ cheaters per minute are served, $h-x$ noncheaters per minute are served so you will be served in $\frac d{h-x}$ minutes. If people didn't think one line was cheating the equilibrium would be to have the noncheater line and the cheater line the same length.  Each arrival would choose a line at random and their expected service time would be the same as if there were no cheaters and one line.  Now it is hard to call the people in the second lane cheaters.

The presence of two processing lanes on the freeway changes things from your analogy.  Now you have your choice of two noncheating lanes approaching the intersection, one of which has cheaters merging in.  It is natural to assume that cars will leave the intersection at the same rate in each lane.  You should be in the lane not affected by the merge of the cheaters.  In the real case that cheaters merge in over a range, the lane affected by cheaters will speed up as the cheaters merge in because there are fewer merging in beyond that point.  Because the lane next to the cheaters is slower people will be merging from that lane into the other one.  Now you need to observe where people merge from one lane to another and the rate as a function of distance from the intersection.  It gets hard.

I find local observation is quite valuable.  Different freeway areas have different lanes that are advantageous.

Comment: Thank you, turns out to be quite simple as you explained.  The throughput of the noncheating line = total throughput - cheater throughput.  And if we graph the function $f(x) = d/(h-x)$, we can appreciate the devastating compounding effect.  When the total throughput is low, each additional cheater causes a significant increase in wait time.

Comment: By the way, after merging in, cheaters usually change lane to pick whichever is the faster lane. In other words, the two lanes move at around the same speed.

Comment: @HaiPhan:  but note that $x$ cannot be greater than $\frac 12h$ in your model because the line would be just as long.  That is the implication of the second half of my first paragraph.  The cheaters in your model can't do more than double your processing time.  On the other hand, you could have cheaters who feel guilty and merge in earlier.  That will slow down the noncheater line even more.  At an extreme, a tiny fraction of noncheaters will get served because cheaters merge in so often.

Comment: Yes, I agree there's a practical upper limit to _x_

Comment: Contrast this with the situation when two lanes are forced to merge.  At the point where the merge is forced, the cars tend to alternate, one from each lane.  Leading up to that point, many cars merge from the lane that is disappearing into the other, so you want to be in the one that is disappearing.  This is similar to what you are calling cheating but doesn't feel the same.

Comment: I'm careful about what I consider cheating. The merging lanes case isn't cheating, it's just being smart. Avoiding a left-turn by going past an intersection and then u-turn isn't cheating either, because you gain at no one's expense. And in the original question, there are legitimate people who change their mind at the last minute and need to merge in, who aren't cheaters. Only the intentional ones are cheaters.

Comment: @HaiPhan The answer $\frac{d}{h-x}$ could also be written as a geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d x^n}{h^{n+1}}$.  This corresponds to the "compounding" approach you were thinking of before: the first term $d/h$ is how long it should have taken you; the second term $dx/h^2$ is the delay due to cheaters entering during the first interval; the third term $d x^2/h^3$ is the delay due to cheaters entering during the second interval; etc.  Sort of an "Achilles and the tortoise" situation...

Answer (score 1):

assume all cheaters come from behind you then they add 1% to the throughput needed at the front of the line based on your estimated percentage of cheaters. even if this is compounded the limits relate when the throughput can erase (1.01)^z where z takes on some natural number as it's value. it's like an amortized mortgage you pay a constant amount to pay off a compounding loan.

Comment: Cheaters who come from the front, from my perspective, aren't cheaters, because they are already in front of me.  So yes, assume all cheaters come from behind.

Comment: okay fixed now get an accountant to figure it out ...

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to regard the exit lane as a queuing system where there are two classes of customers, one with a higher priority than the other, and a single server, the exit.  If the higher priority customers, i.e. cheaters, are class $1$, then the average time they spend in the queue waiting for the exit is
$$W_{q_1} = \frac{\lambda}{\mu (\mu-\lambda_1)}$$
and the average time spent waiting in queue by the class $2$ customers, i.e. good citizens, is 
$$W_{q_2} = \frac{\lambda}{(\mu-\lambda)(\mu-\lambda_1)}$$
where $\lambda_i$ is the arrival rate for customers of class $i$ for $i=1,2$, $\lambda = \lambda_1+\lambda_2$, and the service rate is $\mu$.

This all assumes the system has a steady state and times between arrivals and service times are exponentially distributed, which is probably false, but still it gives you an idea.

By contrast, if all customers are a single class, then the average time in queue is
$$W_q = \frac{\lambda}{\mu(\mu-\lambda)}$$

Reference: *Fundamentals of Queueing Theory* by Donald Gross and Carl M. Harris.